# Is it possible to make a 9x9 table fit within the default margins?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

so I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
   $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$\\
    $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$\\
    $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$\\
    $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$\\
    $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$\\
    $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$\\
    $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}

The character table:

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
    $\chi_{(0,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Using the default margins, it goes beyond the dimensions of the default margins which doesn't make it consistent with the rest of the document, any fixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to an `array` environment (letting you get rid of 160 [!] `$` math-mode markers, center the columns, and reduce the value of `\arraycolsep` from its default value of `5pt` to `3pt`.

I would also use `\phantom{-}` directives to align the positive and negative numbers. Note that since the first data column contains only (positive) numbers, no `\phantom` directives are used in that column.

As the following screenshot shows, the resulting `array` will be contained within the bounds of the textblock; its edges are marked by the thick black lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array,showframe} % don't load 'showframe' in real document

\begin{document}
\[ % no need for an 'align*' env.
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{} c | *{8}{c} @{}}
  +  & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
\hline
\chi_{(0,0,0)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(0,0,1)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,1,0)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1\\
\chi_{(0,1,1)} &1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,0,0)} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1\\
\chi_{(1,0,1)} &1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,1,0)} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\chi_{(1,1,1)} &1 &-1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 &-1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request: The exact same adjustments described above also work for the "first table".

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{array,showframe} % don't load 'showframe' in real document
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default:5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{}c | *{8}{c} @{}}
 +       & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
 \hline
 (0,0,0) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
 (0,0,1) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0)\\
 (0,1,0) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1)\\
 (0,1,1) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0)\\
 (1,0,0) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1)\\
 (1,0,1) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0)\\
 (1,1,0) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1)\\
 (1,1,1) & (1,1,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,0,0) & (0,1,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,0,0)\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you do this with the first table? I like the neatness of this :)

Comment: @Maths - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Answer (score 4):

Let TeX compute the intercolumn spaces.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{showframe} % just to see the page margins

\begin{document}

This is the character table:
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\displaywidth}{
 @{\hspace{3pt}}
 >{$}c<{$}
 @{\hspace{3pt}\extracolsep{\fill}}|
 *{8}{>{$}c<{$}}
 @{\hspace{3pt}}
}
+ & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
    \hline
    \chi_{(0,0,0)} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(0,0,1)} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,0)} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,1)} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,0)} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,1)} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,0)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,1)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
\end{tabular*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\tabcolsep=2.5pt\relax
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
    $\chi_{(0,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
\tabcolsep=2.5pt\relax
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
   $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$\\
    $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$\\
    $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$\\
    $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$\\
    $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$\\
    $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$\\
    $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally, one can set the 2nd table in `\small`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\tabcolsep=2.5pt\relax
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
    $\chi_{(0,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}

{\small
\begin{align*}
\tabcolsep=3.75pt\relax
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
   $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$\\
    $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$\\
    $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$\\
    $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$\\
    $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$\\
    $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$\\
    $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you do something similar for the table above?

Comment: well its the same additional line, but this makes the first table look very compact

Comment: @Maths You can set it differently for each table.  In the latter case, you might consider setting the `tabular` in a smaller font size.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `array` for that.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{}}
  +  & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
    \hline
    \chi_{(0,0,0)} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(0,0,1)} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,0)} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,1)} & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,0)} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,1)} & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,0)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,1)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I prefer these two variants:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{}}
  +  & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
    \hline
    \chi_{(0,0,0)} & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1\\
    \chi_{(0,0,1)} & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,0)} & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,1)} & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,0)} & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,1)} & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,0)} & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,1)} & +1 & -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & +1 & -1
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{}}
  +  & (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) & (0,1,0) & (0,1,1) & (1,0,0) & (1,0,1) & (1,1,0) & (1,1,1)\\
    \hline
    \chi_{(0,0,0)} & 1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1\\
    \chi_{(0,0,1)} & 1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,0)} & 1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(0,1,1)} & 1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,0)} & 1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1\\
    \chi_{(1,0,1)} & 1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,0)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1\\
    \chi_{(1,1,1)} & 1 & -1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}1 & -1
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But will this be within the default margins? as that's my issue

Comment: @Maths Of course yes - I did some settings to make sure that `Overfull \hbox` doesn't happen.

Comment: all solutions provided here are of good quality hence the +1 for all. however for the first table, as mentioned in the above answer, using the technique from the first solution makes everything compact, any ideas to make it 'free'?

Comment: @Maths What do you mean by "free"? Automatic resize if margin exceeded?

Comment: Yup, I mean can we release the little white gaps between entries further enough to which it does exceed the margins?

Comment: @Maths Ah, I suppose you are looking for a `tabularx` answer.

Comment: Since the first data column contains only positive numbers, there's no need for `\phantom` instructions in that column, right?

Comment: @Mico Oh yes. Actually I used "Find and Replace" in my editor, so I did not take note of that. Thanks!