# how to fit this tree within the default margins?

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins

i have the following code and wish it to fit the default margins without making he page vertical, is it possible to do this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\textit{Generator $(12)$}
\[\hspace*{-10em}\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=5em,s sep=2em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$(132)$}
 [,label=above:{$(12)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$(132)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(23)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$(123)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$()$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\rightarrow\hspace*{-10em}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=7em,s sep=4em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$}
 [,label=above:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `pdflscape`, you can use `rotating` package, `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\textit{Generator $(12)$}
\[\hspace*{-10em}\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=5em,s sep=2em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$(132)$}
 [,label=above:{$(12)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$(132)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(23)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$(123)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$()$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\rightarrow\hspace*{-10em}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=7em,s sep=4em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$}
 [,label=above:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\]
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i made a mistake aaah, let me amend the code, and hopegully you can amend the answer :)

Comment: Amended the question. this is how I want it, but this page is landscape. I wish to make this vertical keeping the default margins, while, if needed, to 'shrink' the tree to give a clean output

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do not know why the trees have that large bounding box, i.e. why the negative `\hspace`s are needed. Other than that I would just slightly rearrange them.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\textit{Generator $(12)$}
\[\bgroup\tikzset{label distance=-3.14pt}\hspace*{-10em}\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=2em,s sep=4em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$(132)$}
 [,label=above left:{$(12)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$(132)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$(23)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below left:{$(123)$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$(13)$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$()$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}
\rightarrow\hspace*{-10em}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,l sep=3em,s sep=8em,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill}
[,label=left:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$}
 [,label=above left:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
 [,label=below left:{$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$},edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,above]{$(23)$}}]
  [,label=right:$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$,edge label={node[midway,sloped,below]{$(132)$}}]
 ]
]
\end{forest}}}\egroup
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I am way more sympathetic with these permutation matrices. Whether or not it is necessary to spell all of them out in such great detail rather than just keeping the cycle notation is something that is to be decided by others.

Comment: I am modelling something using particular groups hence need these matrix descriptions

Comment: isn't there a way to shrink the entire tree whilst maintaining the shape?

Comment: something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482599/is-it-possible-to-make-a-9x9-table-fit-within-the-default-margins

Comment: @Math Yes, there is. You should then go with MadyYuvi's solution once they go back to `adjustbox`. I personally am *very* much opposed to shrinking the text just in order to squeeze something on a page. (I am not saying my solution is "better" but just that I am not going to spell this out, the more so since MadyYuvi had `adjustbox` first.)

Comment: i tried her solution and its not what i want. for example, in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482599/is-it-possible-to-make-a-9x9-table-fit-within-the-default-margins, the OP wanted to shrink the figure to fit into the default margins whilst maintaining vertical format, that's what i want

Comment: so something similar what you did in your answer but we see, in your answer, the shaping was out of place, i want to correct this

Comment: @Math If something does not fit on a page, you have basically three options: (1) rearrange things; (2) make the page larger (or rotate it) and (3) shrink it. Of course, you can combine these options. I take you do not want to do (2) and I do not want to do (3) so I am left with (1). You can still shrink it with `adjustbox`, just ask MadyYuvi to revert the original solution but to keep the `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` stuff alive.